# Fixed Tab + Swipe with ListView

Tags: android

I'm doing an app that has mutiple tab and for each tab has its own activity. after putting the code to load the list on one activity; still listview is not visible at all.
here is my code, somebody please help:

```
public class BillsActivity extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String mUrl = BayadCenterConstants.BAYAD_URL_BILLERS;

JSONParsers jsonParser = new JSONParsers(); 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> billerList;
JSONArray billers = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_child_bills);

    /*
     * Check network connection here
     */

    billerList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadBillers().execute();

}

class LoadBillers extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BillsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downlaoding list ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        String json = jsonParser.getBillers(mUrl, params);

        Log.d("Billers JSON: ", "> " + json);

        try {              
            billers = new JSONArray(json);

            if (billers != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < billers.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = billers.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("bid");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String status = c.getString("status");
                    String date_added = c.getString("date_added");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("bid", id);
                    map.put("name", name);
                    map.put("status", status);
                    map.put("date_added", date_added);

                    billerList.add(map);
                }
            }else{
                Log.d("Billers: ", "null");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        BillsActivity.this, billerList,
                        R.layout.tab_child_bills_list_row, new String[] { "bid", "name", "status", 
                                "date_added" }, new int[] { R.id.txtBillerID, R.id.txtBillerName, 
                                R.id.txtBillerStatus, R.id.txtBillerDateAdded });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

this activity is just part of an activity that holds then in tab+swipe manner.
did i miss something with my code?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but onPostExecute executes in the UI Thread :) no need for runOnUiThread.

Comment: after running the app,, tabs are loaded but when I select on the tab that holds the list it doesn't load anything on the listview.. why is that? each tab layout also has its own activity. this is giving me too much problem.